# REST API: 400 Bad Request or 404 Not Found which one should be used when passing parameter with invalid data

Tags: web-services, api, rest, https

I'm building a REST API and I'm getting confuse what error should I throw for the below case.

The Rest API url is,

`https://myapp.com/users/search?q=<search_query>&access_token=<token>&user_type=<type>`

In the above end-point, user_type parameters has the valid values 'admin' and 'standard'. If I get some other value rather than 'admin' or 'standard' what http error should I throw?
It should be 400 Bad Request or 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Status code `404` isn't suitable here since this code says that the resource can't find the current representation. For me, the resource doesn't accept the query parameters provided by the client even before trying to get the representation.

I would say to use a status code `400` with a payload describing the problem. Something like that:

```
{
    "code": "errorcode",
    "description": "The value 'a value' isn't supported for parameter user_type"
}
```

That's the way some tools that have a REST API handle such error in that way. For example:

- **Azure Storage Service** - See this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179357.aspx
- **Parse** - See this link https://www.parse.com/docs/rest#general-responses ("a 4xx status code indicates failure")

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Well - you're asking for our opinion here. Why don't you rely on your own?

Since you brought the two error types up: 404 stand for "Resource not found". That is clearly not the case. Your resource (your API) is found. HTTP Error Code 400 states that the client sent a bad request - ok, your client did not privide correct query variables.

But, check RFC 7231, Section 6.5.1 (which I did for you ;) ):

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Since you did not provide any more information what your client can request and why (is it user input?) it is hard to answer your question.

My Opinion: Answer by HTTP 200 OK (request is ok!) but provide information to let the client know that the request was not acceptable because of some higher (not HTTP related) error.

Cheers.

Comment: Yes it is user input. User can enter whatever he wants. But the input will be validated against the above two values 'admin' and 'standard'. @insaneivan

Comment: I think then you should go for my opinion. No malformed request and resource is found. This is not an HTTP or API-call error. The error is located on a higher level (in your variables) and does not realte to HTTP or your API